# escape special characters like <;>,\

Tags: escaping

I am trying to read the character between > and  in the apex.
For this, I have used below :

1. message.substringBetween('>','</font>');
2. message.substringBetween('&gt','&lt/font&gt');
3. message.substringBetween('>','');

But none of the above is working.
Can anyone suggest, how can I read above character?

Comment: I want to read special character between < and </font>

Comment: Show an example..

Comment: I have string str='>1</font>';                                                                          
decimal num = str.subStringBetween('&gt','&lt/font&gt');                                               The above statement is returning nullpointer exception error